# Is there an alternative driver for canon scanner 3000F on windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, scanner

My good old scanner is a Canon Canoscan 3000F. It seems to be lacking a 64 bit driver on windows, or so it seems when I check [Canon's site](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/scanners/canoscan_series/canoscan_3000f#DriversAndSoftware). I tried Vuescan, which provides alternative drivers for old scanners, [with no luck](http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/canon_3000f.html)

Does anyone know of a way to it functional on Windows 7 x64 ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: The Canon site states `The driver may be included in your OS or you may not need a driver.` Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I have, but the scanner shows as an unrecognized device in windows device manager.

Answer (score 0):

XP Mode might be your best bet. Below is a link to a post on Microsoft Answers which is very detailed and helpful.

[Microsoft Answers](http://In%20Reduced%20Functionality%20mode,%20your%20software%20behaves%20similarly%20to%20a%20viewer.%20You%20cannot%20save%20modifications%20to%20documents%20or%20create%20any%20new%20documents,%20and%20additional%20functionality%20might%20be%20reduced.%20No%20existing%20files%20or%20documents%20are%20harmed%20in%20Reduced%20Functionality%20mode.%20Full%20functionality%20returns%20when%20you%20activate%20or%20convert%20the%20software.)

Answer (score 0):

On the Canon UK website is a driver for Vista (www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/scanners/CanoScan_series/CanoScan_3000F.aspx). It might work with Windows 7.